# Spatio-temporal autocorrelation

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, autocorrelation, glmm, spatio-temporal

I have a huge data frame (300k + rows) on GPS animal positions. 
I want to model the probability of the presence of chamois taking into consideration as variables: distance (from a disturbance), intensity (of the disturbance), altitude.

```
      ID idAnimal        date               lat   lon   alt  dist     intens    park

 1     1 animal_1        11/07/2018 12:00  45.7  6.71  2351    170       143   name2
 2     2 animal_3        11/07/2018 18:00  45.7  6.71  2371    131        71   name5
 3     3 animal_4        12/07/2018 00:00  45.7  6.70  2323     90       102   name5
 4     4 animal_1        12/07/2018 06:00  45.7  6.69  2379    119         6   name3
 5     5 animal_2        12/07/2018 12:00  45.7  6.69  2372    141       152   name5
 6     6 animal_1        12/07/2018 18:00  45.7  6.70  2364    121        25   name2
 7     7 animal_4        13/07/2018 00:00  45.7  6.70  2217    135        39   name1
 8     8 animal_2        13/07/2018 06:00  45.7  6.72  2605    137        96   name2
 9     9 animal_2        13/07/2018 12:00  45.7  6.72  2602     16       100   name1
10    10 animal_1        13/07/2018 18:00  45.7  6.71  2424     48        72   name2
```

I want to create a model that takes into account the spatio-temporal autocorrelation of data. I tried to build a binomial GLMM by adding fictitious points of absence, but I have no idea if this is correct. I also do not know how to take into account the autocorrelation of the data.
I was thinking of splitting up data into a list of dataframes with the following condition:
"one observation per day per animalID". 
Then I'm going to run the model on each of the created subsets.
However, I'm not sure how to get a single output from many models and (most of all) if this process can remove the problem of autocorrelation.

Comment: First, it is not clear what your question of interest is. Then, maybe it might be worth to build first a model without any autocorrelation.

Comment: @Alex.C-L-ReinstateMonica You're right, sorry. I want to model the probability of the presence of chamois taking into consideration as variables: distance (from a disturbance), intensity (of the disturbance), altitude.

Comment: May I ask for a precision: Is your aim to know the probability of a chamois at a given point? To infer what is the impact of disturbance (in that case: on what?).

Comment: @Alex.C-L-ReinstateMonica Yes that's my aim. The disturbance is made of human presence points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding how to model your data, I guess you may divide your map into a grid (i.e. you create spatial point of absences) and have indicator of presence. From that way, you may have only one model. Maybe there is an additional challenge in that altitude may matter a lot here and it might be difficult to create a grid.

You will be interested in a fixed-effect analysis that deploys spatial auto-correlations (eventually in a dynamic way). Please find a recent handbook from the French Institute of Statistics here: https://www.insee.fr/en/information/3635545.
You will be particularly interested in Chapter 7: Spatial econometrics on panel data, and the extension to "7.5.1 Dynamic spatial models". Maybe also in the previous chapters.
An additional challenge might be that you will probably have grid fixed-effects, but also (maybe? maybe not in a first time?) animal fixed-effects.